# Replace/Copy/Duplicate Lines from 2 text documents into a 3rd

Tags: c#, text, replace, copy, duplicates

I have two .txt documents and I would like to search in one of them for a keys from the secoond file. If the keys are found, I want to replace the match with the text that follows the key in the second file. Also, I would like to add a "T" or a "B" depending on the number in the file.

Here is an example of a first file:

```
   1       0010    SOMETEXT/NUMBERS    SOME TEXT, TEXT
   .2      0020    SOMETEXT/NUMBERS    SOME TEXT, TEXT, TEXT
   1       0020A   SOMETEXT/NUMBERS    SOME TEXT,TEXT
   .1      2000    SOMETEXT/NUMBERS    SOME TEXT,TEXT, TEXT
   ..3     9123A   SOMETEXT/NUMBERS    SOME TEXT
   ...     ...     ...                 ...
```

Here is an example of a second file:

```
  0010    ABCD EFG
  0020    C01
  0020A   C02, C3, C004, C9901, C938, C12
  2000    R123, R13, D34 
  9123A   SOMETEXT
  ...     ...
```

From these two files, I would like to use the "keys" from the second file (at the start of every new line). So in this example the keys would be: 0010, 0020, 0020A, 2000, 9123A.  After I have the keys I want to search the first text document in the second column to see if there is a match.  If there is a match (in this case they all match) I would like to replace the text in the first document and create a new document with the updated text. Also, if there are multiple values after the keys in the second file, I would like to copy the lines down.  Look below to see what I mean.

The new document would look like this:

```
   1       ABCD EFG   SOMETEXT/NUMBERS    SOMETEXT, TEXT
   .2      C01        SOMETEXT/NUMBERS    SOME TEXT, TEXT, TEXT
   1       C02        SOMETEXT/NUMBERS    SOME TEXT,TEXT             //--------------------
   1       C3         SOMETEXT/NUMBERS    SOME TEXT,TEXT             // Copied the lines
   1       C004       SOMETEXT/NUMBERS    SOME TEXT,TEXT             // down if there are
   1       C9901      SOMETEXT/NUMBERS    SOME TEXT,TEXT             // multiple values in
   1       C938       SOMETEXT/NUMBERS    SOME TEXT,TEXT             // document 2.
   1       C12        SOMETEXT/NUMBERS    SOMETEXT,TEXT              //--------------------
   .1      R123       SOMETEXT/NUMBERS    SOME TEXT,TEXT, TEXT       //--------------
   .1      R13        SOMETEXT/NUMBERS    SOME TEXT,TEXT, TEXT       // COPIED ALSO
   .1      D34        SOMETEXT/NUMBERS    SOME TEXT,TEXT, TEXT       //--------------
   ..3     SOMETEXT   SOMETEXT/NUMBERS    SOME TEXT
   ...     ...     ...                 ...
```

Also, if the key(s) end with an "A" I would like to add a "T" to the end of the string above. If the key(s) do not end with an "A" I would like to add a "B" to the end of the string above.

Example of a few lines:

```
   .1      R123       SOMETEXT/NUMBERS    SOME TEXT,TEXT, TEXT         B       //key was 2000
   .1      R13        SOMETEXT/NUMBERS    SOME TEXT,TEXT, TEXT         B       //key was 2000
   .1      D34        SOMETEXT/NUMBERS    SOME TEXT,TEXT, TEXT         B       //key was 2000
   ..3     SOMETEXT   SOMETEXT/NUMBERS    SOME TEXT                    T       //key was 9123A
```

---

---

***THE FIRST FILE***

```
  1 0010 142717 PCB, PCA-0320 
  1 0020 CAP-00010G CAP-C,1uF,10%,X7R,0603 
  1 0020A CAP-00010G CAP-C,1uF,10%,X7R,0603 
  1 0030A CAP-00127G CAP,4.7uF,10%,X5R,0805 
  1 0040A CAP-00126G CAP,12pF,10%,50V 
  1 0050A CAP-00131G CAP,1000pF,10%,100V 
  1 0060 134920 CAP-C,0.1uF,10%,10V,X7R 
  1 0060A 134920 CAP-C,0.1uF,10%,10V,X7R 
  1 0070 CAP-00129G CAP,0.01uF,10%,25V 
  1 0070A CAP-00129G CAP,0.01uF,10%,25V 
  1 0080 CAP-00128G CAP,15pF,10%,25V 
  1 0080A CAP-00128G CAP,15pF,10%,25V 
  1 0090A CAP-00132G CAP,0.47uF,10%,10V 
  1 0100 RES-00466G RES,2.7K,1%,1/16W 
  1 0110 RES-00464G RES,1.54K,1%,1/16W 
  1 0120 RES-00461G RES,2K,5%,1/16W 
  1 0130 RES-00460G RES,12.1K,1%,1/16W 
  1 0140 RES-00455G RES,330,5%,1/16W 
  1 0150A RES-00454G RES,51.1,1%,1/16W 
  1 0160 RES-00453G RES,47,1%,1/16W 
  1 0160A RES-00453G RES,47,1%,1/16W 
  1 0170 RES-00458G RES,0,1/16W,0402 
  1 0170A RES-00458G RES,0,1/16W,0402 
  1 0180 RES-00457G RES,15K,1%,1/16W 
  1 0190 RES-00456G RES,1K,1%,1/16W,0402 
  1 0200 RES-00463G RES,10K,1%,1/16W,0402 
  1 0200A RES-00463G RES,10K,1%,1/16W,0402 
  1 0210A RES-00462G RES,1.5M,5%,1/16W 
  1 0220 CAP-00133G CAP,100pF,5%,50V 
  1 0230 LED-00011G LED ARRAY,GY,.02A 
  1 0240 IC-00199G IC,MICRO ARM,NS7520 
  1 0250A IC-00198G IC,VOLT MONITOR RES 
  1 0270A IC-00134G IC,TRAN,RS232,3DX5R 
  1 0280A IC-00196G IC,TRANS,ICS1893BF 
  1 0290A ICP-01006G IC,PLD,NIM-PX-1 
  1 0300 IC-00194G IC,MEM,SDRAM,2MX32 
  1 0310A IC-00083G IC,LOGIC,2 INPUT 
  1 0320A IC-00193G IC,LOGIC,2 INPUT 
  1 0330 IC-00192G IC,VOLT REG,.150A@1.5V 
  1 0340A IND-00009G IND,120nH,100MHz,5% 
  1 0350A IND-00008G IND,25%,.37A,ESR=.3 
  1 0360A IND-00007G IND,120OHM@100MHz 
  1 0370A INT-00112G HDR,2X8,1.27mm,ST,1A 
  1 0380A INT-00113G HDR,2X4,1.27mm,ST,1A 
  1 0390A XTL-00011G CRYSTAL,18.432MHz 
  1 0400 XTL-00012G CRYSTAL,25.000MHz 
  1 0410A CON-00205G CONN,RJ45,SIDE ENTRY 
  1 0420A CON-00181G CONN,RJ45,RA,1.02mm 
  1 0422A ICP-01042G IC,FLASH,NIM-BLT 
  1 0423 122261 ADH, CYANOARYLATE 
  1 0424 70476 ADH,ACCELERANT 
  1 0425 143298 ADH, LOCTITE 3609 
  1 2000 98658-1 LBL,IUC,PCA,S/N 
  .2 0010 74320-27 LBL,IUI,1.0x.25 
  ..3 9000 74320 DWG-A,SPEC,LBL,IUI 
  .2 9000 98658 DWG-A,FAB,LBL,IMP 
  .2 9010 SC12279-1 RIBBON-LBL,PRT,4.33,POLY 
  1 9000 143239 DWG-C,ASSY,ELEC 
  1 9010 143240 DWG-B,SCHEMATIC 
  1 9020 139045 TEST,ICT 
  1 9030 139046 TEST,FCT 
  1 9620 143241 CUSTOMER P/N 
  1 9630 98982-4A PCA REV: 4A
```

***THE SECOND FILE***

```
  0010 BARE PCB
  0020 C40
  0020A C5, C45, C48
  0030A C25
  0040A C17, C18
  0050A C15
  0060 C20, C23,
  0060A C6, C7, C8, C9, C10, C11, C12,C31, C32, C33, C34, C35, C36,C37, C38, C39
  0070 C16, C21, C22, C24, C41, C42
  0070A C3, C19, C43, C44, C47
  0080 C13, C14
  0080A C1, C2
  0090A C26, C27, C28, C29, C30
  0100 R65
  0110 R35
  0120 R34
  0130 R33
  0140 R21, R22, R29, R30
  0150A R28, R31, R32, R37
  0160 R17, R19, R26, R47, R50, R51,R53, R57, R58, R59
  0160A R18, R25, R42, R48, R49, R52,R54, R55, R56, R60
  0170 R23
  0170A R10, R43
  0180 R8, R9
  0190 R13, R14, R15, R61, R62, R63,R64
  0200 R27, R38, R39, R40, R41
  0200A R2, R3, R11, R44, R45, R46
  0210A R1
  0220 C4
  0230 D1
  0240 U1
  0250A U10
  0270A U6
  0280A U5
  0290A U4
  0300 U2
  0310A U7
  0320A U8
  0330 U9
  0340A L2, L3
  0350A L8, L9
  0360A L1, L4, L5, L6, L7, L10
  0370A J1, J2
  0380A J3
  0390A X1
  0400 X2
  0410A J4
  0420A J5
  0422A U3
  2000 TRACKING LABEL
  0423 ADHESIVE
  0424 ACCELERATOR
  0425 ADHESIVE
```

***3RD FILE (HOPEFULLY***

```
  1 BARE PCB 142717 PCB, PCA-0320 B
  1 C40 CAP-00010G CAP-C,1uF,10%,X7R,0603 B
  1 C5 CAP-00010G CAP-C,1uF,10%,X7R,0603 T
  1 C45 CAP-00010G CAP-C,1uF,10%,X7R,0603 T
  1 C48 CAP-00010G CAP-C,1uF,10%,X7R,0603 T
  1 C25 CAP-00127G CAP,4.7uF,10%,X5R,0805 T
  1 C17 CAP-00126G CAP,12pF,10%,50V T
  1 C18 CAP-00126G CAP,12pF,10%,50V T
  1 C15 CAP-00131G CAP,1000pF,10%,100V T
  1 C20 134920 CAP-C,0.1uF,10%,10V,X7R B
  1 C23 134920 CAP-C,0.1uF,10%,10V,X7R B
  1 C6 134920 CAP-C,0.1uF,10%,10V,X7R T
  1 C7 134920 CAP-C,0.1uF,10%,10V,X7R T
  1 C8 134920 CAP-C,0.1uF,10%,10V,X7R T
  1 C9 134920 CAP-C,0.1uF,10%,10V,X7R T
  1 C10 134920 CAP-C,0.1uF,10%,10V,X7R T
  1 C11 134920 CAP-C,0.1uF,10%,10V,X7R T
  1 C12 134920 CAP-C,0.1uF,10%,10V,X7R T
  1 C31 134920 CAP-C,0.1uF,10%,10V,X7R T
  1 C32 134920 CAP-C,0.1uF,10%,10V,X7R T
  1 C33 134920 CAP-C,0.1uF,10%,10V,X7R T
  1 C34 134920 CAP-C,0.1uF,10%,10V,X7R T
  1 C35 134920 CAP-C,0.1uF,10%,10V,X7R T
  1 C36 134920 CAP-C,0.1uF,10%,10V,X7R T
  1 C37 134920 CAP-C,0.1uF,10%,10V,X7R T
  1 C38 134920 CAP-C,0.1uF,10%,10V,X7R T
  1 C39 134920 CAP-C,0.1uF,10%,10V,X7R T
  1 C16 CAP-00129G CAP,0.01uF,10%,25V B
  1 C21 CAP-00129G CAP,0.01uF,10%,25V B
  1 C22 CAP-00129G CAP,0.01uF,10%,25V B
  1 C24 CAP-00129G CAP,0.01uF,10%,25V B
  1 C41 CAP-00129G CAP,0.01uF,10%,25V B
  1 C42 CAP-00129G CAP,0.01uF,10%,25V B
  1 C3 CAP-00129G CAP,0.01uF,10%,25V T
  1 C19 CAP-00129G CAP,0.01uF,10%,25V T
  1 C43 CAP-00129G CAP,0.01uF,10%,25V T
  1 C44 CAP-00129G CAP,0.01uF,10%,25V T
  1 C47 CAP-00129G CAP,0.01uF,10%,25V T
  1 C13 CAP-00128G CAP,15pF,10%,25V B
  1 C14 CAP-00128G CAP,15pF,10%,25V B
  1 C1 CAP-00128G CAP,15pF,10%,25V T
  1 C2 CAP-00128G CAP,15pF,10%,25V T
  1 C26 CAP-00132G CAP,0.47uF,10%,10V T
  1 C27 CAP-00132G CAP,0.47uF,10%,10V T
  1 C28 CAP-00132G CAP,0.47uF,10%,10V T
  1 C29 CAP-00132G CAP,0.47uF,10%,10V T
  1 C30 CAP-00132G CAP,0.47uF,10%,10V T
  1 R65 RES-00466G RES,2.7K,1%,1/16W B
  1 R35 RES-00464G RES,1.54K,1%,1/16W B
  1 R34 RES-00461G RES,2K,5%,1/16W B
  1 R33 RES-00460G RES,12.1K,1%,1/16W B
  1 R21 RES-00455G RES,330,5%,1/16W B
  1 R22 RES-00455G RES,330,5%,1/16W B
  1 R29 RES-00455G RES,330,5%,1/16W B
  1 R30 RES-00455G RES,330,5%,1/16W B
  1 R28 RES-00454G RES,51.1,1%,1/16W T
  1 R31 RES-00454G RES,51.1,1%,1/16W T
  1 R32 RES-00454G RES,51.1,1%,1/16W T
  1 R37 RES-00454G RES,51.1,1%,1/16W T
  1 R17 RES-00453G RES,47,1%,1/16W B
  1 R19 RES-00453G RES,47,1%,1/16W B
  1 R26 RES-00453G RES,47,1%,1/16W B
  1 R47 RES-00453G RES,47,1%,1/16W B
  1 R50 RES-00453G RES,47,1%,1/16W B
  1 R51 RES-00453G RES,47,1%,1/16W B
  1 R53 RES-00453G RES,47,1%,1/16W B
  1 R57 RES-00453G RES,47,1%,1/16W B
  1 R58 RES-00453G RES,47,1%,1/16W B
  1 R59 RES-00453G RES,47,1%,1/16W B
  1 R18 RES-00453G RES,47,1%,1/16W T
  1 R25 RES-00453G RES,47,1%,1/16W T
  1 R42 RES-00453G RES,47,1%,1/16W T
  1 R48 RES-00453G RES,47,1%,1/16W T
  1 R49 RES-00453G RES,47,1%,1/16W T
  1 R52 RES-00453G RES,47,1%,1/16W T
  1 R54 RES-00453G RES,47,1%,1/16W T
  1 R55 RES-00453G RES,47,1%,1/16W T
  1 R56 RES-00453G RES,47,1%,1/16W T
  1 R60 RES-00453G RES,47,1%,1/16W T
  1 R23 RES-00458G RES,0,1/16W,0402 B
  1 R10 RES-00458G RES,0,1/16W,0402 T
  1 R43 RES-00458G RES,0,1/16W,0402 T
  1 R8 RES-00457G RES,15K,1%,1/16W B 
  1 R9 RES-00457G RES,15K,1%,1/16W B
  1 R13 RES-00456G RES,1K,1%,1/16W,0402 B 
  1 R14 RES-00456G RES,1K,1%,1/16W,0402 B
  1 R15 RES-00456G RES,1K,1%,1/16W,0402 B
  1 R61 RES-00456G RES,1K,1%,1/16W,0402 B
  1 R62 RES-00456G RES,1K,1%,1/16W,0402 B
  1 R63 RES-00456G RES,1K,1%,1/16W,0402 B
  1 R64 RES-00456G RES,1K,1%,1/16W,0402 B
  1 R27 RES-00463G RES,10K,1%,1/16W,0402 B
  1 R38 RES-00463G RES,10K,1%,1/16W,0402 B
  1 R39 RES-00463G RES,10K,1%,1/16W,0402 B
  1 R40 RES-00463G RES,10K,1%,1/16W,0402 B
  1 R41 RES-00463G RES,10K,1%,1/16W,0402 B
  1 R2 RES-00463G RES,10K,1%,1/16W,0402 T
  1 R3 RES-00463G RES,10K,1%,1/16W,0402 T
  1 R11 RES-00463G RES,10K,1%,1/16W,0402 T
  1 R44 RES-00463G RES,10K,1%,1/16W,0402 T
  1 R45 RES-00463G RES,10K,1%,1/16W,0402 T
  1 R46 RES-00463G RES,10K,1%,1/16W,0402 T
  1 R1 RES-00462G RES,1.5M,5%,1/16W T
  1 C4 CAP-00133G CAP,100pF,5%,50V B
  1 D1 LED-00011G LED ARRAY,GY,.02A B
  1 U1 IC-00199G IC,MICRO ARM,NS7520 B
  1 U10 IC-00198G IC,VOLT MONITOR RES T
  1 U6 IC-00134G IC,TRAN,RS232,3DX5R T
  1 U5 IC-00196G IC,TRANS,ICS1893BF T
  1 U4 ICP-01006G IC,PLD,NIM-PX-1 T
  1 U2 IC-00194G IC,MEM,SDRAM,2MX32 B
  1 U7 IC-00083G IC,LOGIC,2 INPUT T
  1 U8 IC-00193G IC,LOGIC,2 INPUT T
  1 U9 IC-00192G IC,VOLT REG,.150A@1.5V B
  1 L2 IND-00009G IND,120nH,100MHz,5% T
  1 L3 IND-00009G IND,120nH,100MHz,5% T
  1 L8 IND-00008G IND,25%,.37A,ESR=.3 T
  1 L9 IND-00008G IND,25%,.37A,ESR=.3 T
  1 L1 IND-00007G IND,120OHM@100MHz T
  1 L4 IND-00007G IND,120OHM@100MHz T
  1 L5 IND-00007G IND,120OHM@100MHz T
  1 L6 IND-00007G IND,120OHM@100MHz T
  1 L7 IND-00007G IND,120OHM@100MHz T
  1 L10 IND-00007G IND,120OHM@100MHz T
  1 J1 INT-00112G HDR,2X8,1.27mm,ST,1A T
  1 J2 INT-00112G HDR,2X8,1.27mm,ST,1A T
  1 J3 INT-00113G HDR,2X4,1.27mm,ST,1A T
  1 X1 XTL-00011G CRYSTAL,18.432MHz T
  1 X2 XTL-00012G CRYSTAL,25.000MHz B
  1 J4 CON-00205G CONN,RJ45,SIDE ENTRY T
  1 J5 CON-00181G CONN,RJ45,RA,1.02mm T
  1 U3 ICP-01042G IC,FLASH,NIM-BLT T
  1 ADHESIVE 122261 ADH, CYANOARYLATE B
  1 ACCELERATOR 70476 ADH,ACCELERANT B
  1 ADHESIVE 143298 ADH, LOCTITE 3609 B
  1 TRACKING LABEL 98658-1 LBL,IUC,PCA,S/N B
  .2 0010 74320-27 LBL,IUI,1.0x.25 B
  ..3 9000 74320 DWG-A,SPEC,LBL,IUI B
  .2 9000 98658 DWG-A,FAB,LBL,IMP B
  .2 9010 SC12279-1 RIBBON-LBL,PRT,4.33,POLY B
  1 9000 143239 DWG-C,ASSY,ELEC B
  1 9010 143240 DWG-B,SCHEMATIC B
  1 9020 139045 TEST,ICT B
  1 9030 139046 TEST,FCT B
  1 9620 143241 CUSTOMER P/N B
  1 9630 98982-4A PCA REV: 4A B
```

---

---

**FORMATTING ISSUE:**

```
  1 C10 134920CAP-C,0.1uF,10%,10V,X7R T
  1 C11 134920CAP-C,0.1uF,10%,10V,X7R T
  1 C12,C31 134920CAP-C,0.1uF,10%,10V,X7R T  //THIS LINE SHOULD BE SPLIT INTO 2
  1 C32 134920CAP-C,0.1uF,10%,10V,X7R T
```

Comment: That is quite a lot of code. Can you cut it down to just the bare minimum necessary to understand the question?

Comment: I added a description of the code at the bottom of my post. I would like to keep the code up in case someone wants to run in and see what is going on with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to produce a file like the one that you are expecting.  I'm not sure if this will help with your code because I am kind of confused at the formatting but hopefully it will.  There is probably a way to clean this code up but I don't have the time to dive deep into your problem.  I hope this will help and if not, I am sorry.

I have this first file with the data:

```
1 0010 xxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxx Txxx, Txxx
.2 0020 yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy yyyy yyyy, yyyy, yyyy
1 0020A rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr rrrr rrrr,rrrr
.1 2000 wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww wwww wwww,wwww, wwww
..3 9123A vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv vvvv vvvv
```

Then the second file contains this data:

```
0010 ABCD EFG
0020 C01
0020A C02, C3, C004, C9901, C938, C12
2000 R123, R13, D34
9123A H33333
```

The code then produces a third file with this data:

```
1 ABCDEFG  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxTxxx,Txxx
.2 C01  yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy,yyyy,yyyy
1 C02  rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr,rrrr T
1 C3  rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr,rrrr T
1 C004  rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr,rrrr T
1 C9901  rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr,rrrr T
1 C938  rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr,rrrr T
1 C12  rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr,rrrr T
.1 R123  wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww,wwww,wwww
.1 R13  wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww,wwww,wwww
.1 D34  wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww,wwww,wwww
..3 H33333  vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv T
```

The code looks like this:

```
        var strFileName = DisplayFile("choose file 1", "*.txt", null);
        var strFileName2 = DisplayFile("choose file 2", "*.txt", null);

        StreamReader srInputOne = File.OpenText(strFileName);
        StreamReader srInputTwo = File.OpenText(strFileName2);
        StreamWriter swOutput = new StreamWriter(@"U:\test\ThirdFile.txt");

        Hashtable oneHash = new Hashtable();
        Hashtable twoHash = new Hashtable();
        List <string> recOne = new List<string>();
        List<string> recNew = new List<string>();

        while (srInputTwo.Peek() > -1)
        {
            string line = srInputTwo.ReadLine();
            string[] vals = line.Split(' ');

            twoHash.Add(vals[0], vals[0]);
        }

        srInputTwo.Close();

        while (srInputOne.Peek() > -1)
        {
            string line = srInputOne.ReadLine();
            string[] parts = line.Split(' ');

            if(!twoHash.ContainsKey(parts[1]) && parts[0] != "1")
            {
                swOutput.WriteLine(line);
            }
            else if (!twoHash.ContainsKey(parts[1]) && parts[0] != "1")
            {
                swOutput.WriteLine(line);
            }                
            else if (!twoHash.ContainsKey(parts[1]) && parts[0] == "1")
            {

                swOutput.WriteLine(line);
            }
            else
            {
                var join = string.Empty;

                for (int i = 2; i < parts.Length; i++)
                {
                    join = join + parts[i];
                }

                if (parts[1].Contains('A'))
                {
                    join = join + " T";
                }
                else
                {
                    join = join + " B";
                }

                if (!oneHash.ContainsKey(parts[1]))
                {
                    oneHash.Add(parts[1], join);
                }
            }

        }

        srInputOne.Close();

        srInputTwo = File.OpenText(strFileName2);

        while(srInputTwo.Peek() > -1)
        {
            string line2 = srInputTwo.ReadLine();

            string[] parts2 = line2.Split(' ');

            string join2 = string.Empty;

            for (int i = 1; i < parts2.Length; i++)
            {
                join2 = join2 + " " + parts2[i];
            }

            if (oneHash.ContainsKey(parts2[0]))
            {
                if (join2.Contains(','))
                {
                    for (int j = 1; j < parts2.Length; j++)
                    {

                        swOutput.WriteLine("1 " + parts2[j].Trim(',') + " " + oneHash[parts2[0]].ToString());
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    swOutput.WriteLine("1" + join2 + " " + oneHash[parts2[0]].ToString());
                }
            }

        }

        srInputTwo.Close();
        swOutput.Close();
```

Comment: I believe the issue now is if the two files do not contain all of the same parts. so if the second file did not contain every 4 letter digit in it, how would i go about just keeping them if the 'key' is not matched in the hash?

Comment: If I am understanding your ? you want to know what if a line in the second file is not in the hashset.  Then I would put an if statement in that says if oneHash doesn't contain the key then just print out the line as is or have it write out whatever data you need.

Comment: yeah. would I put that in the while loop for the 2nd file peek? or would I place it somewhere else?

Comment: You're correct. That is where you should put it.  Check the edit to the answer is an idea you could use.

Comment: Okay I added it. However for some reason it does not seem to be hitting the second while loop

Comment: It is not even leaving the first while loop (I don't think) I used some print outs and nothing popped up

Comment: Mine is working with that exact code so make sure that your formatting is right and that you didn't accidentally erase anything like the swOutput.Close().  If that is not closed then it won't write data.  Make sure your StreamReader didn't get changed too.

Comment: Well those are all the same, but what I mean is that it does not get out of the first loop.. I will post my 2 txt files above with what I am using to see if you see a reason why

Comment: sorry had to delete the code in order to fit it.. if the code is needed to be put back up, let me know

Comment: with this new data you are looking at different code. If you take the first few lines of data from the first file and the first line of data from the second file.  What would that look like in the 3rd file.

Comment: the new data I posted is the original format. Right now I have that data being manipulated into the data that is at the top. using my code I changed it to the format of the actual way I wanted it before changing it again to its' final stage. I will delete the data above and repost the data that you have been helping me.

Comment: I updated the data at the top to match what you have helped me with. Now it is in the correct format to create the third file..

Comment: I updated the answer code.  You would have to implement a sort if you care where the information is or maybe rearrange the code but the code now is spitting out a 3rd file just like the one you showed on there just in a different order.

Comment: wow that works nicely! there is one thing though that happens randomly.... I will post it above so you can see it easily

Comment: and also, it does not seem to be finding the lines that have a "." at the very start?

Comment: I added some changes to the condition statements to handle the missing records. They reason it's not splitting those other records properly is because it is splitting on a space so there needs to be a space after each comma or it won't work. C13,C15 needs to be C13, C15

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I really learned a lot about C#!

Comment: No problem.  Look over the code and I'm sure there are many spots you can clean it up.  I didn't really have the time to make it pretty but I'm glad it helped.

Comment: Bringing this up again, I came across an issue with a text file. Do you know how I could add to your code in order to deal with issue of non matching keys.. what I mean is that if the key of `0010` *(or whatever)* doesnt match in the **first** and **second** file then how would I go about reading each file line by line and formatting them that way. so if there wasnt an exact match it would default to matching/formatting them line by line ***(so line 1 in 1.txt will be formatted with line 1 in 2.txt)***